# Rails: Can't seem to sign up users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, registration, form-for

Basically my sign up form is not working. When I sign someone up it states that the user exists

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction 
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") == LOWER('sambam@herpderp.edu') LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

I am unsure what the issue is. Here are some of my model code and controller code.

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :biography, :avatar
has_secure_password
before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
valid_email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.edu/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                  format:     { with: valid_email_regex },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6}, :on => :create   
validates :password_digest, presence: { message: "Password can't be blank" }
validates :biography, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "75x75>" }
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    redirect_to current_school
  end
end
```

School Model

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

School Controller

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController

def create
 school = School.find(params[:name])
 if school
   session[:school_id] = school.id
   redirect_to school_path(school)
 end
end

def show
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @user =User.new
end

end
```

Sign Up Form

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'modal_signinfield', :placeholder => 'Name'  %>
</br></br>
<%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'modal_signinfield', :placeholder => 'Email: Must be .edu'  %>
</br></br>
<%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'modal_signinfield', :placeholder => 'Password: Must be at least 6 letters'  %>
</br></br>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'modal_signinfield', :placeholder => 'Renter Password'  %>
<%= f.submit "Sign Up", :class => 'sign_up_button'%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you log is showing rollback,  it can be assumed that something went wrong with a callback or in your case the User model validation.

Looks like you have a validation that is required, which you are not entering in your signup form.

```
validates :biography, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
```

Either make this conditional for a new_record? or remove it.

Might be worth showing the errors in the form, so you will see what validation errors occurred.

Comment: You sir are amazing, I didn't even catch that, thank you so mucho! :)